# Add vector data to TIFF imagery QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have vector data with field (id,name) and image GeoTIFF format, this two data of the same place.
I want to add name data to each pixel corresponds. how to do it  when I click to any pixel give me the name corresponds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution and I want to share it with you if anyone has the same problem.
You should use this option: iterate over this layer to split by each polygon in vector layer like this caption

[image]

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identify tool: click the icon, then right click on the map canvas and select `Identify all`. The `Identify Results` panel on the right will show you the values form the raster and the polygon:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that for idetifying 2 layer vector and raster in same time what i want it's to add data vector in to metadata raster, like your exemple when u click just to raster i wnat to see also data id is 2

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a misunderstanding: raster data does not have an attribute table, you cant "add" data to each pixel, if that is what you mean?

Comment: yes exactly give data to each pixel if i have vector with 2 polygones(id=1  and id=5)in raster data i will find all pixel scorrespand of polygone 1 are id=1 and pixels correspand of polygone 2 are id=5)

Comment: As I sayed, it is **not possible** to "attach" data to each pixel. Rasters do not work like vectors. What you can do (but I'm not sure if that is what you want): Rasterize the polygons. In this way, you create a **new** raster layer with the pixels corresponding to the attribute value you set, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkY2p.png

Comment: yes i rasterize it but the raster like you say doen't keep attribute table for each pixel

Comment: are you delete the code of splitting? @Babel

Comment: @resuk sorry, don't understand what you're asking...?

Comment: i speak about the python code which you posted to split image but  i had errors with it

Comment: I did not post any python code and did not delete anything from my post - as you can see, since I posted my answer (Dec 29, 2021, at 16:51), it was not edited at all. I'm not sure what you're refering to?

Comment: sorry so someone other who reply to post by code

Comment: There are two other answers - none of them includes any code - not in it's current form nor in an earlier stage, as far as I can see...

Answer (score 1):

There are tools `Raster pixels to points` and `Raster pixels to polygons` in the QGIS Processing toolbox. With these tools you can can convert your raster data into vector data and then you can add your attributes to the features.

Another approach is to add a new band to the raster image and categorize the values of the extra band to correspond with the IDs of your polygons. It is a bit more complicated but doable with GDAL command line utilities.

Comment: the second approche which i want exactly, have code or some documentation to realize that